# Are there no default user pictures to choose from in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, pictures

I am customizing my Windows 8 installation and when I went to change the picture of the user accounts I saw there were nothing to choose from besides images you may already have or photos you can take.

Are there no stock pictures in Windows 8? How to access them / where are they in case there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear to be any stock pictures included, at least any better than the default one.

But you can use any picture you like, just put it in the "My Pictures" folder, you could even copy some user account pictures from XP or Windows 7 install and put in there if you liked those, then:

From the start screen right click on your user name in the upper right corner and select "Change account picture"

.

[image]

.

Then select "Browse" (you can even use a short video or a picture on your camera by selecting "Camera")

.

[image]

.

Here you will see your Pictures folder, (this is were you would put some pictures ahead of time before performing this procedure) C:\Users\your user name\My Pictures

.

[image]

.

Click the white background image in the upper left (image above ^, where it says screenshots in my image) to see all the pictures in the "My Pictures" folder.

Select a picture by a single click (it will put a check in the upper right)

Once selected hit the "Choose image" button

.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any included, however; if you choose browse, the control panel will give you an option to use the Bing application to find one from the internet or navigate your filesystem to find one locally.

Answer (score 0):

The default user account picture images are in the hidden system folder below.
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures`

From [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2749-user-account-picture-change-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: I don't have that folder in my PC :(

Comment: i dont have win 8 so cant check :(. The link says the folder is [hidden](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/394-hidden-files-folders-show-hide.html) did you turn on "Show all hidden files & folders"? [This site](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/27356/windows-8-change-default-picture-for-guest-or-new-account/) shows instructions to access the folder if it helps..

Comment: I ticked that in the View options, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the default XP avatars from C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\User Account Pictures to the Windows 8 Public Pictures folder, where they can be found using the "Change Account Picture" browser.  At first it was strange to see them blurred from being blown up from such low resolution, but now I'm warming up to the "looking through water" artsy effect.

Answer (score 0):

The default user account picture images in windows 8.1 are in the hidden system folder below

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\user.png

For changing all account pictures in your company domain. you can just replace your logo with GPO in that address.