# How do I change my login photo

Tags: windows-8

I would like to change the photo that appears when I login to Windows 8 using my Microsoft account name and password.  I believe this photo is tied to my live.com account, but I can't figure out how to change it.  Please help.

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/a/497395/138343) for screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Put your mouse or swipe down from the top right corner and press the `Settings` button. Then at the very bottom, click `Change PC Settings`.

When it opens, there will be an `Account Picture` link at the top towards the middle, click that and you have the option to browse for a photo or you can take one with a built-in camera.

Comment: The name is identical on tablets, "PC" is Microsoft's new term for "computer", however they haven't found all the strings to convert yet, so some (EG. in Windows Update) still read "Computer".